# How to use Node JS to decrypt a file that was encrypted using C#

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I have files encrypted in C# (using DES, PKCS7). I *need* to decode these files in Node JS.

The code I use to decrypt in C# looks like this:

```
public string SSFile_Reader( string fileToDecrypt )
{
  DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
  {
    Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( "13^07v90" ),
    IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( "13^07v90" ),
    Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
  };
  
  using( FileStream streamToDecrypt = new FileStream( fileToDecrypt, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite ) )
  {
    ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = provider.CreateDecryptor();
    string outputString = "";

    using( CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream( streamToDecrypt, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read ) )
    {
      try
      {
        using( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( stream2 ) )
        {
          try
          {
            outputString = reader.ReadToEnd();
          }
          catch
          {
           //handle error here
          }
          stream2.Close();
          streamToDecrypt.Close();

          return outputString;
        }
      }
      catch( Exception exception )
      {
        //handle error here
      }
    }
  }

  return '';
}
```

I literally need to convert the above to Node JS. I have tried the Node JS code below, but the output is just some random stuff rather than the original encrypted string:

```
const { Readable } = require("stream");
const { scrypt, scryptSync, randomFill, createCipheriv, createDecipheriv } = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');

const [, , pathToEncryptedFile] = process.argv;

if (!pathToEncryptedFile) {
  console.log('No file to decrypt')
  exit()
}

const keyAndIv = '31335e3037763930'; //hex equivalence of 13^07v90
const key = Buffer.from(keyAndIv, 'hex');
const iv = Buffer.from(keyAndIv, 'hex');

const decryptedData = '';

const decipher = createDecipheriv('des', key, iv);

const readableStream = Readable.from(fs.createReadStream(pathToEncryptedFile)
  .pipe(decipher));

readableStream.on("data", (chunk) => {
  decryptedData += chunk.toString()
})

readableStream.on('end', function () {
  console.log({decryptedData})
});

readableStream.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log({err})
});
```

I also tried using [crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/396) to no avail (https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/396).

This is an example of one of the files I need to decrypt: https://files.fm/u/6pewftkk2

I can also give the C# code that does the encryption if the C# code given above for the decryption does not suffice

Comment: *...I have tried below Node JS code:...* And ... what happened?

Comment: ...the output is just some random stuff rather than the original encrypted string (sorry for the incomplete info. Question also updated)

Comment: The question is not clear, [encoding is not encryption](https://www.packetlabs.net/encryption-encoding-and-hashing/). Are you encoding or encrypting the file? Can you specify the algorithm you want to use?

Comment: Since you store the plaintext in `outputString` anyway, you can actually load the ciphertext directly without streams, e.g. with `readFileSync()` and decrypt the data with `createDecipheriv()`. For a larger ciphertext, which is read successively from the filesystem, and its resulting plaintext, which is written successively to the filesystem, `pipe()` would be a simple solution.

Comment: @Thecave3 Sorry for the error (I clearly said _how to *decrypt*..._ so the encode was my error). Algo is DES with PKCS7 padding. [This is the gist for the code that I use for the encryption](https://gist.github.com/damms005/b99e8d531b552b90396c48abe9cf1ef9)

Comment: @Topaco My apologies for the confusion. I have updated the original question and title. I have files encrypted in C#. I want to decrypt those files in Node JS

Comment: Yes, that is actually clear. My question is rather whether you need to read the ciphertext as a stream when it is apparently so small that you can store the plaintext in `outputString`. Or the other way around, if you read a ciphertext via stream from a file (because it is very large), shouldn't you write the plaintext via stream to a file?

Comment: There really is no strict implementation details. I just need whatever works. The whole stream thing and plaintext `outputString` is just one of the many attempts I made to achieve my aim. Any implementation that helps me achieve the aim of decryption is okay by me, whether streams or memory, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible variant is to load the ciphertext completely from the file system and decrypt it:

```js
var crypto = require('crypto')
var fs = require('fs')

const algorithm = 'des'; // defaults to 'des-cbc';
const password = 'Password used to generate key';
const key = '13^07v90';
const iv = '13^07v90'; 

const ciphertext = fs.readFileSync('<path to high_classes.ssdata>');
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
const plaintext = decipher.update(ciphertext, '', 'utf8') + decipher.final();
console.log(plaintext);
```

which outputs the following plaintext (for the linked file):

```
SSS1
SSS2
SSS3
```

---

Alternatively, especially for large data, the plaintext can also be streamed to a file. To do this, replace the last block with:

```js
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('<path to high_classes.ssdata>');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('<path to file where decrypted data should be saved>');
readStream.pipe(decipher).pipe(writeStream);
```

which creates a file containing the decrypted data.

---

Note that DES is outdated and insecure these days. Using the key as an IV is also insecure. Typically, a random IV is generated during encryption and passed to the other side along with the ciphertext (usually concatenated).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, @Topaco. When I tried the code you posted above, I get an error on the line `const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)`. The error, summarily, is:

`node:internal/crypto/cipher:116
    this[kHandle].initiv(cipher, credential, iv, authTagLength);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`

Comment: I get your point with respect to DES being outdated. I wrote this code in 2015/2016. It's a really old codebase I am actually re-writing it with Node JS, and I am removing this file encryption feature entirely because in hindsight, it has not helped in any way to the service we use it for. If anything, it has made Customer support and ease of development a pain in the neck. Thanks for the heads-up though

Comment: I hope the error I am getting is not related to PKCS7 padding? Also, I should mention that I am using `Node.js v17.0.1`

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. You can run the code online on replit: https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/GrowlingValuablePriorities. Since there is no access to the filesystem, the data must be imported from the file `2301...71d6` (hex encoded). Please run this code in your environment. If this works, check in your environment the imported ciphertext with `const ciphertext = fs.readFileSync("<high_classes.ssdata>")` and output it with `console.log(ciphertext.toString('hex'));`. It should correspond to `2301...71d6` and decryption should work.

Comment: Yes, the replit works. As you can tell already, I am not a Node JS expert, so I will need some help with getting this fix, please. I have no clue on how to resolve this `initiv` error. Any clue, please? (by the way, my own hex is `2301...71fd`, specifically `2301fd2cfdfdfdfdfdfdfd57786a71fd`)

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere - Have you tested the replit code in your environment (just copy/paste)? Is the error also triggered by this code?

Comment: Yes . I have tried it on my local env. That's why I said `the replit works`. You think I should open another issue for this specific `initiv` error thingy?

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere - _...The replit works..._ may mean that you were able to run the code **on replit** successfully or it may mean that the replit code works **in your environment**. So it's still not clear to me if the replit code runs in your environment (copy/paste/run).

Comment: Copying and pasting the replit to my env "as-is" (without any modification). It also gives the `initiv` error, the same way the solution you provided above gave same error. Tha't why I'm thinking that it is another issue totally with my local env that needs some expert insight into

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere - If the code doesn't run, it's most likely indeed a problem with your environment, probably even NodeJS 17. For NodeJS 17 there are issues for this error message, e.g. [#14532](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532) or [#11708](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11708). Try to solve the problem with the workarounds described there (maybe [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14532#issuecomment-947012063) one). Possibly this is related to the deprecated DES algorithm.

Comment: So my error was actually about the [legacy provider](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/40478) issue as you rightly mentioned. Thanks man, you saved my day!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240508/discussion-between-damilola-olowookere-and-topaco).